# Invalidating panel scrollbars

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, panel

I have set a Panel to AutoScroll = True.

I host a button in this panel.

When I set the button to a new location outside the panel's visible area...

```
.Location = New Point(2000, 0)
```

... this doesn't make the scrollbars appear.

How could I force the panel to invalidate / check again if the scrollbars should be shown?

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

I need to set the button's parent to something else, then add it to the panel again which raises the ControlAdded event.